# Cannot add foreign key with "set default" as on delete

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, constraints, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB and now wanted to add a foreign key to my database table. I'm having problems when trying to use `set default` as my on delete constraint;=. (The default of the `user_id` in the `pages` table is 1)

```
`alter table `pages` add constraint pages_user_id_foreign foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete set default`
```

However, when I'm doing this, I'm getting the error

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'project.#sql-add_38' (errno: 150)`

When I look at the last foreign key error, I'm getting the following output

> 160322 12:40:56 Error in foreign key constraint of table `project`.`pages`:
>   Alter  table `project`.`pages` with foreign key constraint failed. Parse error in ' foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete set default' near ' on delete set default'.

When I do it without `on delete set default` it works without any problems

```
`alter table `pages` add constraint pages_user_id_foreign foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`)`
```

Same goes, if I use `set null` for my on delete condition

```
alter table `pages` add constraint pages_provider_id_foreign foreign key (`provider_id`) references `providers` (`id`) on delete cascade
```

Somehow, only the `set default` doesn't work, but the error message doesn't give me enough information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got it. Seems like InnoDB doesn't allow for `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT`

> SET DEFAULT: This action is recognized by the MySQL parser, but both InnoDB and NDB reject table definitions containing ON DELETE SET DEFAULT or ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT clauses.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html